SMAC with MFFacade returns None
I'm using SMAC (Sequential Model-based Algorithm Configuration) to optimize hyperparameters for training a model (specifically, a PPO agent) using Stable Baselines3. During the training phase, the model trains successfully and I can save it without issues. However, when I call smac.optimize() to run the optimization, it returns None instead of returning the optimal hyperparameters. Anyone has a clue of what it can be? Thanks!
Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

model = genericSolver.GenericSolver()

logger = Logger(filename)

max_budget = 100000
min_budget = 7500

scenario = Scenario(model.configspace, 
                        deterministic=True, 
                        seed=-1,  
                        n_trials=100,
                        walltime_limit=EARLY_STOPPING,
                        min_budget=min_budget,
                        max_budget=max_budget, 
                        )  

initial_design = MFFacade.get_initial_design(scenario, n_configs=3)
    
intensifier = SuccessiveHalving(
        scenario=scenario,
        incumbent_selection="highest_budget",
    ) 

smac = MFFacade(scenario=scenario,
                    target_function=model.train, 
                    initial_design=initial_design, 
                    intensifier=intensifier,
                    overwrite=True)

incumbent = smac.optimize() -> This is None``` 

## GENERICSOLVER.PY is like this:

ENV = 'LunarLander'
BATCH_SIZE = 256

class GenericSolver:
    @property
    def configspace(self) -> ConfigurationSpace:

        cs = ConfigurationSpace(seed=0)
        learning_rate = UniformFloatHyperparameter("learning_rate", lower=1e-5, upper=1e-2, default_value=1e-3, log=True)
        discount_factor = UniformFloatHyperparameter("discount_factor", lower=0.9, upper=0.999, default_value=0.99)
        gae_lambda = UniformFloatHyperparameter("gae_lambda", lower=0.8, upper=0.999, default_value=0.95)  
        
        cs.add_hyperparameters([learning_rate, discount_factor, gae_lambda])

        return cs
    
  
    def train(self, config: Configuration, seed: int = None, budget: float = None) -> float:

        if ENV == 'CartPole':
            env = gymnasium.make('CartPole-v1')
        else:
            env = gymnasium.make('LunarLander-v2')
        
        print(f"Training with config: {config}, seed: {seed}")

        ppo_params = {
            'policy': 'MlpPolicy', # indicates that the policy will be represented by a feedforward neural network
            'env': env,
            'learning_rate': config['learning_rate'],
            'gamma': config['discount_factor'],
            'n_steps': 1024,
            'batch_size': 64,
            'n_epochs': 10,
            'gae_lambda': config['gae_lambda'],
            'clip_range': 0.2,
            'ent_coef': 0.0,
            'vf_coef': 0.5,
            'max_grad_norm': 0.5,
            'verbose': 1
        }

        agent = PPO(**ppo_params)

        total_timesteps = int(budget)
        print("Total TimeSteps: ", total_timesteps)
        num_agents = 5
        num_updates = total_timesteps // BATCH_SIZE
        
        rewards = {}  # Track rewards over training
        
        # Agent training
        for update in range(1, num_updates + 1):  
            agent.learn(total_timesteps = BATCH_SIZE)

            total_reward = 0
            for agent_index in range(num_agents):
                individual_reward = GenericSolver.evaluate_agent(agent, env)
                agent_key = str(agent_index + 1)
                if agent_key in rewards:
                    rewards[agent_key].append(individual_reward)
                else:
                    rewards[agent_key] = [individual_reward]
                total_reward += individual_reward
            mean_reward = total_reward / num_agents
           
            if 'mean_reward' in rewards:
                rewards['mean_reward'].append(mean_reward)
            else:
                rewards['mean_reward'] = [mean_reward]

        env.close()

        agent.save("ppo_multifidelity_agent")
        
        return -np.mean(rewards['mean_reward']) # Calculate negative mean for SMAC's minimization

I've checked: Exception Handling (there are no errors), The configuration of your SMAC scenario (seems to be okay), and even when i evaluate the model it works properly but the incumbent is still None. I have the same code snippet without multifidelity and it works.
